# Expression for early 20th century industry magnate

Tags: phrase-requests

I remember reading a very fitting, playful, 2-words expression for for early 20th century industry tycoon who teared their employees bad. Please help reminding me by listing synonyms.

Comment: Jack: the Ripper?

Comment: The word 'tycoon' I believe is Japanese. But that's a separate matter. Perhaps 'business magnate'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for [robber baron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robber_baron_%28industrialist%29)?

> **Robber baron**
>
> typically applied to businessmen who used what were considered to be exploitative practices to amass their wealth